# Handling async and storage in Ionic 4 to make an api call

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my app I'm saving a token for connecting with an api using Ionic Storage, the thing is I don't which is the correct form to deal with asynchronous, because I don't get the token in the correct timing to make the call to the api.

player.page.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.playerService.getPlayers().subscribe(data => {
      this.players = data;
    });
  }
```

global.service.ts

```
  getToken(){
    this.storage.get(this.token_key).then((val) => {
      this.token = val;
    })
    return this.token;
  }
```

player.service.ts

```
  getPlayers() {
    return this.api.get('GetPlayers');
  }
```

api.service.ts

```
 getHeaders() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.global.getToken()
      })
    };
    return httpOptions;
  }

  get(route:any)
  {
    return this.http.get(this.global.urlAPI + route , this.getHeaders());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In global.service.ts, in the function getToken() , where you are assigning value to this.token when the promise is resolved but you should return a promise like this -

```
getToken() {
    return this.storage.get(this.token_key);
}
```

and then in the caller -

```
getToken().then((value) => {
    //do assignment here
}
```

The way you are doing it currently , will always return the value from function even before the promise is resolved.

EDIT: According to your comment. You want to return a value after the promise is resolved. Since you can not do that from inside a promise , what you can do is make the function async and do the assignment using await. then return your object, like -

```
async getHeaders() {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + await this.global.getToken()
        })
    };
    return httpOptions;
}
```

Then call this function wherever you want to like this -

```
getHeaders().then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

because async functions always return a promise . You can also do promise chaining but I think this approach is cleaner

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but still don't realized how can I get it assigned in something I want to return. I put this on headers now:   `getHeaders() {
    let token;

    this.global.getToken().then((value) => {
      token = value;
    });

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      })
    };
    return httpOptions;
  }`

But doesn't work, how can I return that well? I want to return the Headers.

Comment: Please check the answer. I have updated it according to your comment